# Does Firebase Analytics for Unity3D track in-app purchases automatically?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

Does Firebase Analytics for Unity3D track in-app purchases automatically, or do I have to track them explicitly using the LogEvent feature?

Answer (score 0):

In App Purchase is tracked automatically on both Android and iOS.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en